# elm-mdl: How to push a record from tab X into the model of tab Y and update tab Y view?

Tags: elm, elm-mdl

I'm using the demo codebase of elm-mdl as a starting point for my elm project.  I have a situation where I need to click a button on one tab (e.g. "tab X") and mutate the state of a different tab (e.g. "tab Y").

Every way I've wired it up so far does not work. This seems like an odd case because the parent of all tabs (e.g. Layout) in the demo codebase is "Demo".  It seems in my case that the dependency graph become convoluted because the effect would reach across "Demo" children.

How can this be done?  I'm running 0.18.0.

https://github.com/debois/elm-mdl/tree/v8/demo

Comment: Can you provide a simple example? It would be much easier to help with some code that reproduces the problem you're facing. ellie-app.com is a nice place to build such example.

Comment: First, make sure you keep the state in your model. So when the update function handles the message produced by the button, it should only update the state; it shouldn't do anything with tabs, parents, children... none of that stuff. Your tabs (views) simply reflect the current state. Simple example: say you have a Textfield on one tab and you want to display its content in another tab. All you need is a String in your model with the Textfield's contents; then have both tabs render the same String (one in a Textfield and another as say... a span.

Answer (score 0):

I've done an example playing around with what I've understand from your question.

I think your issue have to be that you are not passing the model through your tabs , so they are not rendering data related to the current state, instead you should be taking data from the initial model which always keeps inmutable.

Starting from the example code you should have this:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    Tabs.render Mdl
        [ 0 ]
        model.mdl
        [ Tabs.ripple
        , Tabs.onSelectTab SelectTab
        , Tabs.activeTab model.tab
        ]
        [ Tabs.label
            [ Options.center ]
            [ Icon.i "info_outline"
            , Options.span [ css "width" "4px" ] []
            , text "About tabs"
            ]
        , Tabs.label
            [ Options.center ]
            [ Icon.i "code"
            , Options.span [ css "width" "4px" ] []
            , text "Example"
            ]
        ]
        [ case model.tab of
            0 ->
                tab0 model

            _ ->
                defaultTab model
        ]
```

My working example is [here](https://ellie-app.com/yX4bsdsvrga1/1)